# What does it mean when console says "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I am trying to create a function that draws cards from a deck but whenever I run it, the console gives me an error message saying: "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined". How come the function can't count how many entries are in my array?

```
  function draw() {
  var suitsdraw = suits[Math.floor(Math.random()*suits.length)];
  var suits = ["Hearts","Clovers","Spades","Diamonds"];
  var numberdraw = number[Math.floor(Math.random()*number.length)];
  var number = ["A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K"];
  console.log(suitsdraw);
  console.log(numberdraw);

}
draw();
```

Comment: you're attempting to access the arrays before they're defined.

Comment: Reorder your statements so you assign values **before** you use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message says that `suits` is `undefined`. Why is that the case?

Because you're trying to access `suits` even before it is defined. Swap the first two lines to get rid of the error.

```
var suits = ["Hearts", "Clovers", "Spades", "Diamonds"];
var suitsdraw = suits[Math.floor(Math.random() * suits.length)];
```

But then, you'll get the same error, but on line 3. See what's the issue?

Swap lines 3 and 4 and you're good to go.

```
var number = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"];
var numberdraw = number[Math.floor(Math.random() * number.length)];
```

PS. Use meaningful variable names and use camelCase convention.